# How to call the moment a cycle (time) starts/loops?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a different word to describe the moment at which a cyclic time duration 'loops around'. I am using 'start' right now, but this seems like the wrong word for this job as this actually only describes the first time the cycle is started.

To give this some context: I am creating an application in which people can select a cycle (week, month, year) and the day at which this cycle should 'loop', e.g. "Monday", or "the 20th day of each month" or "Last day of the year".

Comment: This situation is often encountered in frame-based executive architectures. In this case the term *start of frame* is used. In your case perhaps *start of cycle or period* might work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the word **restart** because your cycle is starting again, and not starting for the first time.

(as defined on google)

> [restart](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=strict&q=restart%20definition) - start again

Answer (score 1):

Try **recommence**.

Re[commence](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commence) by Merriam Webster

> To start or make a start again, begin again

There is a word **recapitulate** which is less used to mean what is [defined below by Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recapitulate)

> To repeat a phase or stage of

Although it is used to talk evolutionary cycles, it can be squeezed or stretched cogently to fit somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

**Recur** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recur)

> *verb* 4. to occur again after an interval; occur time after time
>
> *"the cancer recurred"*
> *"There is only a slight chance that the disease will recur."*
> *"The same problem keeps recurring."*

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're doing a calendar app.  The way calendar apps that I have seen (eg Google Calendar, Sunrise, Ios Calendar) refer to this is **repeat**.